# Code to insert arbitrary XML string into XML document by XPath

Tags: java, xml, dom, groovy, xpath

I am attempting to create a script that wraps a Groovy class that will take the following arguments:

1. An input XML file to update.
2. An arbitrary snippet to insert into the input file (might not even be well-formed in an of itself; it would become part of a larger well-formed document).
3. XPath for the marker element (used for positioning the snippet in #2).
4. An action (insert before, insert after, append child).
5. Optional output XML file.

I'm at a loss for finding an API that will allow me to:

1. Find a node by XPath and
2. Cram XML from a String adjacent to the node.

Does anyone have some ideas for technologies that I can combine to achieve this effect? Small examples would be especially useful.

Comment: The not well-formedness requeriment is an indication of bag design in most cases. Besides that, I wouldn't reinvent the wheel: [XQuery Update Facility](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what I was trying to do is non-trivial and would have required a much larger framework than what I had time for. I ended up abandoning this endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

If the snippet is well-formed most DOM implementations I've seen will also support the non-standard DocumentFragment node type which allows you to inject dom nodes from string.

EDIT: Quick Google search throws up some JavaDocs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DocumentFragment.html
IIRC the api works like this (pseudo code):

```
parent = find_parent_node_of_fragment(document);

fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendXML("<my>xmlstring</my>");

parent.appendChild(fragment);
```

If you don't have this luxury or if your string is not well formed there is the option to inject CDATA.

If you can't make do with injecting CDATA (because you essentially want to affect nodes that follow, for instance the new node must become the parent of old nodes which will be enclosed in the new document), you could try an XSLT transformation.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but I don't see a method called `appendXML` on `DocumentFragment`.